# NVENC ME-only mode OpenEncodeSessionEx() fail with "invalid struct version" error

Tags: nvidia, opticalflow, nvenc

I got stuck with a strange behavior, trying to initialize NVENC in ME-only mode. `OpenEncodeSessionEx()` always fail with #15 - `"This indicates that an invalid struct version was used by the client."`

Parameters struct is as follow:

```
  NV_ENC_OPEN_ENCODE_SESSION_EX_PARAMS session_params = {
    .version = NV_ENC_OPEN_ENCODE_SESSION_EX_PARAMS_VER, 
    .deviceType = NV_ENC_DEVICE_TYPE_CUDA,
    .device = ctx,
    .reserved = 0,
    .apiVersion = NVENCAPI_VERSION,
    .reserved1 = 0,
    .reserved2 = NULL
  };
  int ret = encOpenEncodeSessionEx(&session_params, &encoder->enc);
```

I tried to invoke it from different C and Golang environments, but whatever I do I get that error. Encoder from NVENC samples just crashed (segfault). Decoder works flawlessly, while encoder doesn't.

Does anyone know, what exact conditions may cause the error #15 - `NV_ENC_ERR_INVALID_VERSION`?

I upgraded Cuda to 10.2 with 440.82 driver - no luck. Tried to downgrade to Cuda 10.0 - still the same. I use `1060ti` GPU.

Anyone help me please))

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally figure it out.

It was so stupid of me but the problem was in the `static` keyword (C-language). I wrote simple wrapper to call NVENC function, like this:

```
static NVENCSTATUS encOpenEncodeSessionEx(NV_ENC_OPEN_ENCODE_SESSION_EX_PARAMS *params, void **encoder) {
  return nvenc_api.nvEncOpenEncodeSessionEx(params, encoder);
}
```

Use it in this manner and you're always get `NV_ENC_ERR_INVALID_VERSION` error. Just remove `static` keyword and the function works as expected.

I have no idea, if it is expected behavior or not, but it works. 
Thanks to all.